# Does Servlet return response after doGet method has finished?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, long-polling

Obviously, the `doGet` method has a return type of void, so, it doesn't return anything. In this sense, I'm using the word "return" to mean send the response back to the client that requested it.

I'm trying to implement a long-polling Servlet. It would be beneficial for it not to send a response until I have something that I would like to send back. So, in the doGet method I add the connected user's ID and AsyncContext to a map:

```
private ConcurrentMap<String, AsyncContext> contexts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
//...in the doGet method when I need to add the context...
contexts.put(userId, context);
```

Then, when I have something to send back, I can retrieve the appropriate context and write to it's responses output stream:

```
AsyncContext context = contexts.get(userId);
PrintWriter writer = context.getResponse().getWriter();
writer.write("something to send to the client");
```

But, the client never seems to receive the response. Looking at the Network tab in the developer console of the browser, I can see the GET request is sent and then returns (with a status of 200). This occurs before I actually send something back. Which is leading me to believe that after the doGet method is finished the response is returned. And perhaps because of this, after this point, nothing can be sent to the client because the connection is not opened.

Does the doGet method send the response to the client once the method is finished executing? If this is the case, how can I keep the connection open for a long-polling effect?

Comment: You're correct in that the doGet method will respond once the method is finished executing. I would suggest looking into Asynchronous Servlets for this type of support. Basically you'll create an asynchronous context to run some code, and then some other methods to call when the code is finished. I haven't tested this myself, so hopefully it would something that works for you.

Comment: I should have stated that I am in fact using asynchronous servlets. I thought that retrieving an AsyncContext would have been enough to infer. Sorry for the confusion. But would a response be able to be sent to the client even after the initial response was sent (finish of method execution)?

Comment: If you're interested in the async servlet, here's an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/mdeimel/sitemesh3-jetty-async/blob/master/sitemesh3-jetty-async/src/main/java/com/example/AsyncServlet.java) I created for a separate issue. Note: the root of the project will explain how to build, test and run.

Comment: @mnd looking at the code provided, I see that you call start on the asyncContext and implement a runnable. This could possibly fix my issue. But to understand, when you call start on the asyncContext does this prevent the response from returning to the client until I explicitly send it?

Comment: yes, the `doGet()` should not return until the `asynContext` has been marked as completed, which is why the `complete()` method is called.

Comment: @mnd ah perfect, and once the asyncContext has completed, if I wanted to send another piece of data to that client, I would need a new AsyncContext object?

Comment: Once you get a running asyncContext, you could add multiple runnables to it (I believe), but I haven't ever tried creating a new AsyncContext once one finishes, it's worth a shot.

Comment: @mnd thanks for patience with me, however I found that even calling startAsync should prevent the doGet method from sending the response. According to [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/async-servlet/async-servlets.html) resource from Oracle: "...it starts an AsyncContext by calling: request.startAsync(request, response). This will notify the Web Container that at the end of the request call it should free the handling thread and leave the connection open so that other thread writes the response and end the connection." So, I shouldn't have to call start()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own questions: `Does the doGet method send the response to the client once the method is finished executing?`

Yes, when the doGet (or any HttpServlet method, ex: doGet, doPost, etc.) method finishes executing it sends the response back to the client.

`If this is the case, how can I keep the connection open for a long-polling effect?`

Using asynchronous Servlets (which I was using, however, I found my particular problem must be elsewhere, yet these answers are still relevant to the questions asked). On the ServletRequest object call the startAsync method, like so:

```
AsyncContext context = request.startAsync(request, response);
```

"This will notify the Web Container that at the end of the request call it should free the handling thread and leave the connection open so that other thread writes the response and end the connection."[Reference Link.](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/async-servlet/async-servlets.html)

Also, I will add the solution to my particular problem (the client wasn't receiving the response) was because in my Servlet, I wasn't calling the complete method on the AsyncContext object:

```
asyncContext.complete();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the response stream is flushed and closed when *doGet()* finishes executing.

Keeping UI threads occupied for extended periods of time violates Java Enterprise best practice.

Recommend you rather return immediately if nothing to respond, and implement a timer on the client (browser) side to poll the server for results every so often.

Comment: That would be polling and not long-polling. There are asynchronous servlets for use cases such as long-polling. Take a look [on Oracles website](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/async-servlet/async-servlets.html) . So now that I know it does return after the methods execution. I'm wondering could I send a response again, using the AsyncContext I retrieved?

Comment: Also, since you made a statement that "keeping UI threads occupied for extended periods of time violates Java Enterprise best practice", thus saying, long-polling is a bad approach (despite being very popular for this particular use), could you point me to some resources that verify this statement?

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the link. According to the example there, you're supposed to initialize async contexts in doGet() and fulfill long polling in doPost() by completing pending contexts.

Comment: The basis of my "best practice" claim is that Java application servers use thread pools to manage threads for incoming requests. If you tie up all the threads in that pool, your application becomes unresponsive to additional requests. Related to this, see [this article](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/swchan2/archive/2013/06/06/asynchronous-servlet-and-java-ee-concurrency-utilities) about using managed thread pools for async servlets.

Comment: Interesting read. Your right about needing to have threads open for additional requests. But I believe that's the whole point of asynchronous Servlets. They free the threads which handle requests so they can be used for other requests. Which is also beneficial for implementing a true long-polling system (much more efficient than traditional polling).

Comment: Thanks for the info about thread handling in async servllets, that's very good to know.